# MS app center does not update for Android app

Tags: android, visual-studio-app-center

I am using the app center to update app so that users could get the reminder during app launch.

For the same app(the same application id), I got master and one dev branch. Compiled app(release version) from master can get the in app reminder successfully.

However, when I cut dev branch from master and create another project in app center, the in app reminder does not work at all.

I have reviewed the MS doc and tried manual check update, tried to check AppCenter enable or Distribute enable status, and check app secret. Everything is good.

Also I tried with latest app center library 4.3.1. It is the same with current version 4.1.0.

Then I set the app center logs to VERBOSE for more info.

First case is the log from dev branch. There is new version available in app center.

2022-02-22 13:06:11.804 23859-24576/? D/AppCenterDistribute: Distribute workflow will be resumed on activity resume event.
2022-02-22 13:06:11.804 23859-24576/? I/AppCenter: Distribute service started from application
2022-02-22 13:06:11.818 23859-24576/? I/AppCenterDistribute: Distribute service has already been enabled.
2022-02-22 13:06:11.822 23859-23859/? D/AppCenterDistribute: Resume distribute workflow...
2022-02-22 13:06:11.823 23859-23859/? D/AppCenterDistribute: InstallerPackageName=null
2022-02-22 13:06:11.823 23859-23859/? D/AppCenterDistribute: Get latest release details...
2022-02-22 13:06:11.824 23859-23859/? D/AppCenterDistribute: Check if we need to report release installation..
2022-02-22 13:06:11.824 23859-23859/? D/AppCenterDistribute: Current release was already reported, skip reporting.
2022-02-22 13:06:13.486 23859-23859/? I/AppCenterDistribute: No release available to the current user.
2022-02-22 13:06:13.486 23859-23859/? D/AppCenterDistribute: Calling listener.onNoReleaseAvailable.

Second case is the log from master. There is no new version available from app center.

2022-02-22 13:38:40.245 25722-27054/? D/AppCenterDistribute: Distribute workflow will be resumed on activity resume event.
2022-02-22 13:38:40.245 25722-27054/? I/AppCenter: Distribute service started from application.
2022-02-22 13:38:40.272 25722-27054/? I/AppCenterDistribute: Distribute service has already been enabled.
2022-02-22 13:38:40.384 25722-25722/? D/AppCenterDistribute: Resume distribute workflow...
2022-02-22 13:38:40.385 25722-25722/? D/AppCenterDistribute: InstallerPackageName=null
2022-02-22 13:38:40.386 25722-25722/? D/AppCenterDistribute: Get latest release details...
2022-02-22 13:38:40.387 25722-25722/? D/AppCenterDistribute: Check if we need to report release installation..
2022-02-22 13:38:40.387 25722-25722/? D/AppCenterDistribute: Current release was already reported, skip reporting.
2022-02-22 13:38:43.125 25722-25722/? D/AppCenterDistribute: No sessions were logged before, ignore sending of the distribution start session log.
2022-02-22 13:38:43.126 25722-25722/? D/AppCenterDistribute: Check if latest release is more recent.
2022-02-22 13:38:43.126 25722-25722/? D/AppCenterDistribute: Latest release more recent=false
2022-02-22 13:38:43.126 25722-25722/? D/AppCenterDistribute: Calling listener.onNoReleaseAvailable.

Third case is the log from master branch. There is new version available in app center.

2022-02-22 14:04:11.854 27871-28744/? D/AppCenterDistribute: Distribute workflow will be resumed on activity resume event.
2022-02-22 14:04:11.854 27871-28744/? I/AppCenter: Distribute service started from application.
2022-02-22 14:04:11.866 27871-28744/? I/AppCenterDistribute: Distribute service has already been enabled.
2022-02-22 14:04:11.880 27871-27871/? D/AppCenterDistribute: Resume distribute workflow...
2022-02-22 14:04:11.881 27871-27871/? D/AppCenterDistribute: InstallerPackageName=null
2022-02-22 14:04:11.881 27871-27871/? D/AppCenterDistribute: Get latest release details...
2022-02-22 14:04:11.882 27871-27871/? D/AppCenterDistribute: Check if we need to report release installation..
2022-02-22 14:04:11.882 27871-27871/? D/AppCenterDistribute: Current release was already reported, skip reporting.
2022-02-22 14:04:13.735 27871-27871/? D/AppCenterDistribute: No sessions were logged before, ignore sending of the distribution start session log.
2022-02-22 14:04:13.735 27871-27871/? D/AppCenterDistribute: Check if latest release is more recent.
2022-02-22 14:04:13.735 27871-27871/? D/AppCenterDistribute: Latest release more recent=true
2022-02-22 14:04:13.736 27871-27871/? D/AppCenterDistribute: Latest release is more recent.
2022-02-22 14:04:13.736 27871-27871/? D/AppCenterDistribute: Calling listener.onReleaseAvailable.

I noticed that for the second and third case from master, there are more logs like below.

D/AppCenterDistribute: No sessions were logged before, ignore sending of the distribution start session log.
D/AppCenterDistribute: Check if latest release is more recent.
D/AppCenterDistribute: Latest release more recent=true

I do not know what caused this because both master and dev branch are using the same app center version.

Could anyone help on it?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you try the latest App Center SDK version ([4.4.2](https://github.com/microsoft/appcenter-sdk-android/releases/tag/4.4.2))? Also please make sure that you created the correct [new release](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/sdk/distribute/android#how-do-in-app-updates-work) and use the right [distribution group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/sdk/distribute/android#use-private-distribution-group).

Comment: You are right. I checked the distribution group again. It is private on default. I need to switch to public. Now it works. Thank Anastasia for your help!!